# Правильно сделан класс, для работы с _API_ новой почты?

Tags: php, ооп, api, curl

```
class API
{
public $apiKey     = '** key here **';
public $entryPoint = 'https://api.novaposhta.ua/v2.0/json/';

public function getRegions()
{
    return $this->requestToAPI('getAreas');
}

public function getCities()
{
    return $this->requestToAPI('getCities');
}

private function requestToAPI($method, $model = 'Address')
{
    $params = array(
        'modelName'    => $model,
        'calledMethod' => $method,
        'apiKey'       => $this->apiKey
    );
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->entryPoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($params));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    $decodedResponse = json_decode($response, true);
    return $decodedResponse;
}
}
```

Comment: С какой целью спрашиваете? что то не работает? Или с точки зрения красоты и опрятности кода?

Comment: Спрашиваю с точки реализации кода и его валидности

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Публичные поля класса `$apiKey`, `$entryPoint` не очень правильно.
2. `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false` всё же лучше проверять
3. Отсутствует проверка на ошибки `curl_`. А вдруг хост не найден или запрос составлен не верно?
4. Ответы от сервера можно не тупо в массив перегонять, а в класс (но это зависит от задачи).

Comment: По поводу второго пункта: если ставить проверку на сертификат то у меня получается curl_exec === false

Comment: Правильно у вас получается. Нужно сам сертификат подставлять в опцию `CURLOPT_CAINFO`

Comment: А сам сертификат мне надо получить у Новой Почты ?

Comment: @ВалераБондаренко, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23032165/how-do-i-keep-my-cacert-pem-current-for-security-reasons-when-using-curl

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант можно сделать вот так:
Выделить абстракцию API:

```
class Api {
    protected function send($url, $params) {

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        if(curl_exec($ch) === false) {
            throw new Exception('Нет ответа от сервера');
        }

        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $decodedResponse = json_decode($response, true);
        return $decodedResponse;
    }
}
```

Наследовать класс, так как потом вам надо будет получать не только от новой почты, но и от других API и не только постом:

```
class ApiNewPost extends Api {
    private $apiKey = '** key here **';
    private $entryPoint = 'https://api.novaposhta.ua/v2.0/json/';


    public function requestToAPI($method, $model = 'Address')
    {
        $params = array(
            'modelName'    => $model,
            'calledMethod' => $method,
            'apiKey'       => $this->apiKey
        );

        return $this->send($this->entryPoint, json_encode($params));
    }
}
```

определить интерфейс ответа от АПИ:

```
interface ResponseApi {
  public function getData();
}
```

А для регионов и городов создать отдельные классы:

```
class Regions implements ResponseApi {

    private $api;

    function __construct(Api $api) {
        $this->api = $api;
    }

    public function getData() {
        return $this->api->requestToAPI('getAreas');
    }
}

class Cities implements ResponseApi {

    private $api;
    function __construct(Api $api) {
        $this->api = $api;
    }

    public function  getData() {
        return $this->api->requestToAPI('getCities');
    }
}
```

Вот такой вот вариант

```
$cities = new Cities(new ApiNewPost());
$regions = new Regions(new ApiNewPost());
```